# Finish can only be called once : Android

Tags: android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

Recently updated Build: 2.3.1, AI-162.3871768, 20170401,

AI-162.3871768, JRE 1.8.0_112-release-b06x64 JetBrains s.r.o, OS Mac OS X(x86_64) v10.11.6 unknown, screens 1440x900; Retina

Switching back to Android 2.2.2 did not help either. Successfully able to build from command Line though(MacOX Terminal)

Answer (score 2):

Delete your `$HOME/.gradle` directory (or on Windows, `%HOME%\.gradle` folder). The next execution of gradle will rebuild this. (It will require some downloads, so make sure you have an internet connection).

You can try just deleting `$HOME/.gradle/caches`, but this will not solve the problem in all cases.

Answer (score 1):

I have similar issue on 2.3.1

I tried using the Android 2.4 Preview 4 but that did not help. I am able to build from command line too.

[Android-Studio-2.3.1-Gradle-Sync](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E8Gmu.png)

Answer (score 1):

It happens when Android Studio creates two instances of gradle. I tried clearing the gradle cache or even deleting the .gradle but did not help. All this problem started when I deleted my old project repo and re-pulled it and imported to my Android Studio.

Best is to delete all your gradle instance from your home directly before your re-import your project Android Studio.

Answer (score 0):

Android Studio started behaving like this after I tried building with the command line(osx) using ./gradlew

What helps is running the studio with sudo:

`sudo /Applications/Android\ Studio.app/Contents/MacOS/studio`

I wonder if theres a fix to this problem that allows the studio to be started normally as well.